# C# - Restrict value entered to between 0.0 to 1.0 in a textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I am new to C# and WPF. I have a textbox in my WPF application and I want to limit the value entered by user in the textbox between 0.0 and 1.0. How do I do that?

Any help would be really helpful.

Comment: You could use Extended WPF Toolkit, which includes a numeric up down text box. It will be easier to restrict input on a control like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work for you, as you will also get the value:

```
double valueEntered;
if (!double.TryParse(textBoxName.Text, out valueEntered)
    // value is not a valid double
    return;
else
    if (valueEntered < 0 || valueEntered > 1)
        // value is valid
        return;
    else
        // value is not valid
        return;
```

For a better implementation you should show us the XAML and the code-behind of your Window.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same with the help of Properties, if you are following `MVVM`

```
private double  _MyLimittedValue;
public double  MyLimittedValue
  {
    get { return _MyLimittedValue; }
    set {
          if (value < 0.0 || value > 1.0) { value = 0.0; } 
          _MyLimittedValue = value; 
        }
  }
```

Then bind the `MyLimittedValue` to the `Text` of textbox with `"mode=TwoWay,updatesourcetrigger=propertychanged"`.

So The text in the textbox becomes `0.0` in case you enter any other value.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: absolutely..! thanks for the corrections

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you

```
private void TexBoxName_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    var patten = @"^(0(\.\d*)?|1(\.0*)?)$";
    Regex regex = new Regex(patten);
    e.Handled = !regex.IsMatch(e.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using ranges. Try using [RangeBase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.rangebase(v=vs.100).aspx) variants viz; ScrollBar, ProgressBar and Slider.

In your case Slider is the natural choice and would be best.